# Print a single large number with underlined 3-digit groups as in a tibble?

Tags: r, tidyverse, largenumber, tibble

Example:

```
# tidyverse packages are supposed to be installed
require(tibble)
set.seed(20180819)
large_int <- floor(runif(1)*1e12)
as_tibble(large_int)
```

This sample code produces on most consoles (inside RStudio it does) :

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
     value
     <dbl>
1 697358430130
  ---   ---
```

In fact the underlined number is more like ̲6̲9̲7358̲4̲3̲0130 but underlined digits are tricky to produce on stackoverflow

Here is my question how to produce the same output for the value without using a tibble ?

Comment: You could look through the source code https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/tree/master/R

Comment: I have spent some time looking at the source code but I cannot figure where and how it is done

Comment: This is done by the pillar package, see https://github.com/r-lib/pillar#usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to hplieniniger, I can answer my own question

```
require(pillar)
pillar(123456789)
```